# How to Gatsby Link for 'mailto'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm making a blog with gatsby but, the `Link` doesn't work for `mailto`

Hhere is my codes. It brings me to `http://localhost:8000/mailto:kjcoco13@gmail.com`
I want to use this `Link` for external.

```js
<Link to='mailto:kjcoco13@gmail.com'></Link>
```

Comment: [maybe this helps](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mailgo/)

Comment: Thanks, but i dont wanna use plugin. Isn't there another way?

Comment: The Gatsby <Link /> component is for linking between pages within your site. For external links to pages not handled by your Gatsby site, use the regular HTML <a> tag. [check out here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/linking-between-pages/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gatsby's `<Link>` component extends from the `@reach/router` (from React) and it's intended to use only for internal navigation. From [Gatsby's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/linking-between-pages/):

> The Gatsby `<Link />` component is for linking between pages within your
> site. For external links to pages not handled by your Gatsby site, use
> the regular HTML `<a>` tag.

In your case, since you're not using any kind of internal navigation, you should use a regular `<a>` tag, you can't use the `<Link>` component. Use:

```
<a href='mailto:kjcoco13@gmail.com'>Your text</a>
```

Comment: This still throws error that the "to" property is required on Gatsby's Link, any idea how to address that ?

Comment: You **can't** use `Link` to place external reference like `mailto` does. It must  be treated as a standard anchor tag (`<a>`)